# Struts 2 session attribute not displaying in jsp

Tags: session, attributes, struts2

I have an action class for a Login page where I am setting a session attribute thus:

```
ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
context.getSession().put(username, getUsername());
```

I am able to access the session attribute through the Action class thus:

```
System.out.println("Username from session: " + context.getSession().get(username).toString());
```

But when I try to access the same attribute through a subsequently displayed jsp, it does not display anything:

```
Welcome <s:property value="#session['username']" />
```

just displays:

Welcome

Please help as to the correct syntax for retriving session attributes.

Comment: You need quotes around username when you place the value of `getUsername()` in session. Otherwise, the session key is the value of username, not the literal string "username".

Answer (score 10):

**LoginAction**

```
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("username", getUsername());
```

---

**Get username at** :

**1) OtherAction**

```
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("username");
```

**2) .jsp**

```
<s:property value="#session['username']" />
```

***or***

```
${username}
```

---

> Implementing **[SessionAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html)** is more preferred.
>
> See also :
>   **1. [How do we get access to the session](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html)**
>   **2. [How do we get invalidate the session](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/how-do-we-get-invalidate-the-session.html)**

Answer (score 1):

> Implementing SessionAware is more preferred.

This certainly makes things easier. It allows you to manipulate the session in your struts action class as a map structure.

From the jsp page I generally access my session objects like the following:

```
<s:property value="%{#session.username}" />
```

or for complex objects in session, like a user object with name and password for instance:

```
<s:property value="%{#session.user.username}" />
<s:property value="%{#session.user.password}" />
```